# Does XMLSpy integration package work with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, xmlspy

I recently acquired XMLSpy 2013 and was naturally excited to see there was a Visual Studio integration package. I'm running VS 2012, but nowhere on Altova's download page does it mention compatibility requirements/limitations.

So I followed the steps on the Altova download site (basically just run the package and you're done). Nothing changed in VS. So I decided to download the 1326 page PDF manual for XMLSpy to see if there was some extra help in there:

http://www.altova.com/documents/XMLSpyPro.pdf

On page 490, it mentions going into your VS/Common7/IDE directory and running `devenv.exe /setup` which I did. After that, again, nothing changed.

Has anyone had any success with getting this integration package to work? I can find almost no information by searching the web.

I actually created a support ticket with Altova for the issue as well, but thought I'd try here for some first hand experiences.

Answer (score 2):

Whelp, Altova support responded to my ticket. The answer is, since Visual Studio is a 32-bit only application, XMLSpy integration will not work when running the 64-bit version of XMLSpy/XMLSpy integration package.

This is despite the fact that both a 64-bit version of XMLSpy AND a 64-bit version of the Visual Studio Integration package exist side-by-side on the download page (as of writing this answer). I have a feeling that it might only exist for the Eclipse integration.

http://www.altova.com/download/xmlspy.html

Once I installed the 32-bit versions of XMLSpy/Integration package, it all worked as promised. I hope this helps someone in the future at least.

Comment: I found that the XMLSpy 2014 32-bit integration package will not install if you have only XMLSpy 64-bit installed. You need XMLSpy 32-bit installed to integrate with Visual Studio.